# How can i save a 3D Object in Google Tango?

Tags: google-project-tango

Is it possible to save a 3D object in Google Tango and then detect it?

example: i want to save my car in it. Can Google Tango now detect every car of the same model as "my car". I just want to know if it is possible already with Google Tango , or do i have to write an application for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there isn't yet any Tango application available to the public that can capture a 3D object like a car, save it, and then recognize even that same individual car again later.

The Constructor app is I think the most sophisticated 3D model capture app publicly available. It only captures and saves 3D scenes. It can't separate objects like a car from the rest of the scene, like the road it's parked on or the wall behind it etc. You could open the saved scene in a separate application, like a 3D studio, and edit the scene like any other, then continue passing the model to other (non-Tango) applications. But that's a human/tool workflow.

The rest of the app you're describing would have to later recognize other 3D objects in captured 3D scenes by matching at least some distinctive features of the saved earlier capture. I don't know of any app that does that. And I'm not sure that the Tango hardware currently available to the public is fast enough to do that, nor the Google webservices that support more sophisticated intelligence about what Tango captures. And recognizing the same model car, but with different colors/options, dirty/scraped, etc is a really tall order for Tango at this time.

But it does sound like a killer app. Somebody push the envelope and make this happen!